Ec2 instance nextjs build issue in t2micro
When I try to build in ec2 instance for nextjs app it got stuck I don't know why? And in local machine the build size is 600mb so I can't send it to GitHub and pull it on ec2 instance so can anyone tell me what I have to do
Clone the code from GitHub run the npm I command after that npm run build and it got stuck den I tried to ctrl +c command to stop it won't stop after that I close that ec2 instance and den again I try to open the same instance it won't opening .I want to know the reason and what steps needed to solve this issue

Unfortunately, you have not provided enough detail for us to be able to assist you. For tips on asking a good question, please see: How do I ask a good question?

Please provide more details about the error messages or logs you see when the build gets stuck.

I've encountered this issue several times in the past. It's because of lack of memory. t2.micro only has 1 GB of memory. Building is relatively memory-intensive so you need adequate amount of it, otherwise it either crash or just hangs.
As a temporary measure (not recommended) you can try adding a swap space, try at least 4 GB to start. e.g.:
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile

If it doesn't solve the issue, try increasing the swap or better yet get a better specced instance.
Also, I suggest using tg4.small which has bigger memory and better performance. It's free at the moment (and has been free for the past 2-3 years). Just keep in mind it is ARM, not x86.
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t4/

When building a Next.js project on an EC2 t2.micro instance, you might encounter performance issues due to the limited resources (1 vCPU and 1 GB of memory) available on this instance type. How to solve it? there are many ways to resolve it :
Upgrade your instance type
Optimize Your Build
Increase Swap Space
or add the following command on npm run build
NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=512" next build

